# Checking if matrix of 1s and 0s are connected - C++

Tags: c++, matrix

The goal is to create a matrix where all the 0s are connected (touching either up, down, left or right). I generated a 10/19 matrix of 0s and randomly added 1s. Now I want to step through the matrix and change values such that all 0s are connected, but I am struggling with that part. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  //generate matrix of 0s
  int map[10][19] = {{0}};
  int a = 10;
  int b = 19;

  //display matrix

  for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
          for (int j = 0; j < b; ++j) {
              std::cout << map[i][j] << ' ';
          }
          std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   cout << "\n" << endl;


  //adds 1s to matrix
  for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < b; ++j) {
                  map[i][j] = 0 + rand() % 2;
          }
  }

  //display matrix
  for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
          for (int j = 0; j < b; ++j) {
              std::cout << map[i][j] << ' ';
          }
          std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   cout << "\n" << endl;
```

First output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Second output:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: Do you expect the solution to be optimal, i.e. you want to flip the minimal number of `1`s?

Comment: maybe you should take a more constructive approach, using maze generation for example

Comment: Should the 0s/1s ratio be balanced? Any shape of the 0s path would be good enough?